# How To Call MySQL Stored Procedure With Output Parameter Using DBeaver

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

Hopefully a fairly simple issue. I have a MySQL stored procedure that uses both input and output parameters. I'd like to call it in a standard DBeaver script, but it doesn't seem to like the output parameter. Example below:

```
DECLARE oJSON LONGTEXT;
CALL myProc(8,1,oJSON);
```

If I refactor the proc to not have the output variable and just execute the CALL statement everything works as it should. Not sure if I need to change something in settings or what; any advice is appreciated!

Comment: SP output parameter is placed into local variable. For to retrieve its value you must execute `SELECT oJSON;` in the same batch after CALL stmt.

Comment: I apologize that this was unclear, but “doesn’t seem to like the output parameter” = errors out on that line. It never even gets to the CALL statement.

Comment: Maybe you try to execute your 2 code lines not as stored procedure but as anonymous code block? In this case you'd use user-defined variable `CALL myProc(8, 1, @oJSON); SELECT @oJSON;` without DECLARE.

Comment: Ensure that DBeaver is configured to handle variables correctly. You can enable variable processing in the “SQL Processing” settings:
Go to Window > Preferences > Database > Editors > SQL Editor > SQL Processing.
Look for the Parameters section and adjust the settings as needed.  Check here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566119/dbeaver-how-to-declare-variables-and-use-them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56566119/dbeaver-how-to-declare-variables-and-use-them)

Comment: @Akina That was the trick - if you make it a formal answer I'll accept. Thank you!

Comment: Formally this is a duplicate. See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/q/1009954 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/64136275

Comment: Except neither of those mention DBeaver, which in my searches does seem to be a key in helping people find the answer they seek.